# Pushing object into Array of Arrays retains pointer to original object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, pass-by-reference

I was wondering if anyone could help provide context on this one.

With the below example:

```
const finalArray: any[][] = []
const accumulatedArray: any[] = []

const ids = ['1','2']
for (const id of ids) {
    accumulatedArray.push({
        id: id,
    })
}

finalArray.push(accumulatedArray)

accumulatedArray.length = 0 // remove elements from array

console.log(finalArray)
```

The above code will output `[ [] ]`, which took me by surprise, I was expecting to see `[ [ { id: '1' }, { id: '2' } ] ]` but I can achieve this by creating a new array using a spread operator:

```
finalArray.push([...accumulatedArray])
```

**question is**
Why does the element in the array of arrays (`finalArray`) point to the `accumulatedArray` ?

Comment: Because `finalArray.push(accumulatedArray)` is pushing that reference, it is not making a new array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value

Comment: Not sure why I thought it would work differently because it was an array of arrays, as opposed to just passing a reference with a standard array. 

Fair enough, thanks @epascarello